# Log4j2 blocking threads and application is becoming unresponsive

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using Log4j2 with async logging. There are more than 10 threads running parallel in my application and one thread is blocking all other threads.

Thread dump shows below.

```
"Scheduler_Worker-7" #143 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fae2ac55800 nid=0x18fc runnable [0x00007faceab12000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:338)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.MultiProducerSequencer.next(MultiProducerSequencer.java:136)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.MultiProducerSequencer.next(MultiProducerSequencer.java:105)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer.publishEvent(RingBuffer.java:465)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.dsl.Disruptor.publishEvent(Disruptor.java:331)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerDisruptor.enqueueLogMessageWhenQueueFull(AsyncLoggerDisruptor.java:236)
    - locked <0x00000005522ce890> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.handleRingBufferFull(AsyncLogger.java:246)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.publish(AsyncLogger.java:230)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.logWithThreadLocalTranslator(AsyncLogger.java:202)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.access$100(AsyncLogger.java:67)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger$1.log(AsyncLogger.java:157)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.logMessage(AsyncLogger.java:130)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.ExtendedLoggerWrapper.logMessage(ExtendedLoggerWrapper.java:222)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.log(AbstractLogger.java:2117)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2034)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1899)
    at com.ragi.common.util.Log4jWrapper.debug(Log4jWrapper.java:106)
```

and other threads stack is like below

```
"Scheduler_Worker-6" #142 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fae2ad2c800 nid=0x18fb waiting for monitor entry [0x00007faceac13000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerDisruptor.enqueueLogMessageWhenQueueFull(AsyncLoggerDisruptor.java:236)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000005522ce890> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.handleRingBufferFull(AsyncLogger.java:246)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.publish(AsyncLogger.java:230)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.logWithThreadLocalTranslator(AsyncLogger.java:202)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.access$100(AsyncLogger.java:67)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger$1.log(AsyncLogger.java:157)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.logMessage(AsyncLogger.java:130)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.ExtendedLoggerWrapper.logMessage(ExtendedLoggerWrapper.java:222)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.log(AbstractLogger.java:2117)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2022)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1875)
    at com.ragi.common.util.Log4jWrapper.debug(Log4jWrapper.java:94)
```

This clearly shows that **Scheduler_Worker-7** thread is holding lock on 0x00000005522ce890 and other threads (Example is **Scheduler_Worker-6**) are waiting to lock 0x00000005522ce890.

Also, from heap dumps, I observed that log ring queue buffer is full. As I am using default [DefaultAsyncQueueFullPolicy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.11.2/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/DefaultAsyncQueueFullPolicy.html), when the buffer is full, the new log events should go directly to the appender instead of the buffer.

Why Scheduler_Worker-7 thread is holding lock on object for so much time and went to TIMED WAITING state and other threads which are trying to log went to blocked states.

Note: There are no deadlocks observed from thread dump.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Because i'm facing the exact issue right now.